# How to adjust y-axis ranges dynamically is ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

How can I adjust y-axis so that the annotations are also shown properly in this kind of plot?

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(diamonds, aes(x = cut, y = depth)) +
  facet_wrap(~ color) +
  stat_summary(fun.y = sum, geom="bar", fill = "yellow", aes(label=cut, vjust = 0)) +
  stat_summary(fun.y = sum, geom="text", aes(label=cut), vjust = 0)
```

[image]

Now for example in facet G annotation for 'Ideal' is not shown properly. Y-axis range should be calculated dynamically, so that there is always some space for annotation above bars. So I can not use fixed y-axis ranges.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about using `+ scale_y_continuous(expand=c(0.15,0))` after your existing code:

`expand=` expects a 2-number vector of multiplicative and additive scale factors

[image]